# Is there a benefit to calling Application.Run in a C# Winforms Application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm designing a set of sequential modal dialogs. The following code seems to work, with no problems whatsoever. What would I gain by creating a custom ApplicationContext and passing it to Application.Run or, alternatively, passing the last modal dialog to Application.Run in lieu of calling ShowDialog? (Edit: Obviously calling Application.Run(...) would replace Application.Exit())

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form1 f = new Form1();
        f.ShowDialog(); //Show a modal dialog
        Form1 f2 = new Form1();
        f2.ShowDialog(); //Chain another modal dialog
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Comment: In your case there's not much difference (because of `ShowDialog`) but just know that because you are using modal dialogs, it can cause issues if you have multiple forms, like trying to switch from a modal dialog to a non-modal dialog while both are open. You are also running the risk of having multiple UI threads in your application.

Comment: Also, `Application.Exit` should be called from within a message loop, it causes the `Application.Run` to return. If you tried using it in one of your forms you may get unexpected results since there is no `Application.Run` that its running inside.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you want to structure your program this way then there is no point in calling Application.Run().  No point in calling Application.Exit() either, it already terminates when your Main() method ends.

The Form.ShowDialog() method already calls Application.Run() under the hood.  The basic way by which a dialog becomes *modal* and why your code does not immediately resume to the next statement after ShowDialog().  Like it does when you use Show() instead.  Not until that dispatcher loop ends, triggered by closing the form or setting the DialogResult property.

Which is something you *normally* need to test for by checking the ShowDialog() return value.  Right now the user has no good way to end your app when the first window appears, that can be pretty confusing.